# Cannot access class in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, class

I have created an ASPX web application, that I have compiled and works fine when running through Visual Studio on my local PC.

However, on the server I get the error message

**Compiler Error Message: BC30451: 'epoDB' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
**

epoDB is a name of a class that I have that contains several methods. I am not using a "Code-Behind" file, this is just a separate file epoDB.vb.  When I publish this website it is creating a 60 KB DLL in the BIN folder.  I have checked the webConfig and it is set properly to allow all assemblies.

Here is some code: (ASPX PAGE)

```
<% @ Import Namespace="epoApprover" 
If Not Action = "X" Then Decrypted = epoDB.AES_Decrypt(RawString)
%>
```

The first time it hits this method AES_Decrypt, I am told epoDB is not declared.

Here is the epoDB.vb

```
Public Class epoDB    
    Public Shared Function AES_Decrypt(ByVal input As String) As String
       'decryption method
        Return decrypted
    End Function
End Class
```

This EpoDB.vb is a separate file.  I have a few classes and it compiles into a 60KB epoApprover.dll , yet I don't seem to be able to access any of these classes.
Using .NET 4.0  / IIS6  / Windows 2003 64-bit.

I have tried many things, such as putting these classes in App_Code, leaving them on the root, yet nothing seems to work -- I think I am missing a fundamental.  Any advice?

Comment: Have you tried fully qualifying the name?  That would be my first diagnostic step

Comment: Have you added a reference to epoApprover in your executing app

Comment: Is this (epoApprover.dll) file in your bin directory?

Comment: I tried fully qualifying the name, to epoApprover.epoDb.AES_Decrypt()   but then it tells me that epoApprover is not declared.  The DLL was placed in the BIN directory, yes.  
@MikeTWebb,  how do I go about doing that?

Comment: @User...you should be able to rright click on you project and "Add Reference" or there will be a References folder wher you right click and "Add Reference"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out IIS was just setup as a web folder. Once I converted it to a web application it was able to find everything. I knew it was something fundamental!

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing your code with a `Page` declaration.

```
<% @ Import Namespace="epoApprover" 
If Not Action = "X" Then Decrypted = epoDB.AES_Decrypt(RawString)
%>
```

So:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="epoApprover"%>

<%     
    If foo Then
       ....
    End If    
%>
```

Though for `inline` style (not `CodeFile` nor `CodeBehind`) code is in:

```
<script runat="server">

   `Sub procs, Functions, etc.

</script>
```

Your `.vb` file should be in `App_Code`. Unsure how your code above worked on your local PC.

Hth...